# Load a javascript plugin after another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on my website 2 typewriter plugins. Both are in the same box. First it's typing just one sentence, second one have the like 4 sentences and it's erasing one before the second one can appear. How can I start the second typewriter "type" after the first one has finished?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var text = $(".js-typewrite").text();
    var stop = text.length;
    var count = "0";
    $(".js-typewrite").text("");

    var type = function() {

        count++;
        if (count <= stop) {

            $(".js-typewrite").text(text.substr(0, count));

        } else {

            var write = clearInterval(type);

        }

    }

    var write = setInterval(type, 60);

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 100 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting) {
        delta /= 2;
    }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {

        that.tick();
    }, delta );




};

window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
            new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = "";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
</script>
```

Comment: do some reading about asynchronous function calls & callback functions

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeout` to have that delay and to call one function after the other with a time gap.

SYNTAX:

```
setTimeout(function(){
//your code here
})},2000);
```

//2000 is 2 second delay

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I think i don't know how to write it.
` setTimeout(function() {

            that.tick();
        }, delta )},200);
`

Comment: I think `that` might not be defined there!! Can you provide more code to check

Comment: <div class="js-typewrite">Hi! I'm Andrei.</div>


                       
                            <span class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "I study Multimedia Design.", "I Love Design & Photography.", " I&#39;m looking for an internship."]'>
                                <span class="wrap"></span>
                            </span>
                       
The div it's from the first javascript and the span is for the second javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery,  try using [jQuery.defered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or [defered.promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)